# How to verify the call to super using sinonjs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, class, sinon

I have a javascript/typescript class (`AAA`) that extends another class (`BBB`). The API of class `BBB` is stable but the implement is not yet. I just want to unit test some functions in class `AAA` only. So I need to create an instance of class `AAA` but not yet successful because of calling the constructor of class `BBB`. This is my [example](https://github.com/mrviit/HelloSinon):

BBB.ts:

```
class BBB {
    constructor() {
        throw new Error("BBB");
    }
    public say(msg: string): string {
        return msg;
    }
}

module.exports = BBB;
```

AAA.ts:

```
const BB = require("./BBB");

class AAA
    extends BB {
    public hello(): string {
        return super.say("Hello!");
    }
}
module.exports = AAA;
```

test script:

```
const AA = require("../src/AAA");

import sinon from "sinon";

describe("Hello Sinon", () => {
    describe("#hello", () => {
        it("#hello", async () => {
            const stub = sinon.stub().callsFake(() => { });
            Object.setPrototypeOf(AA, stub);
            let a = new AA();

            sinon.spy(a, "hello");

            a.hello();

            sinon.assert.calledOnce(a.hello);
            sinon.assert.calledOnce(stub);

            // how to verify that super.say has been called once with string "Hello!"?
        });
    });
});
```

I'm using [sinonjs](https://sinonjs.org/) . But in this case I cannot create an instance of `AAA`. And if we can, how to verify that `super.say` functions has been called?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**: Now I can create the instance of `AAA` but I don't know how to verify the call to `super.say`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my issue:

```
describe("Hello Sinon", () => {
    describe("#hello", () => {
        it("#hello", async () => {
            const stub = sinon.stub().callsFake(() => { });
            Object.setPrototypeOf(AA, stub);
            let a = new AA();
            const say = sinon.spy(a.__proto__.__proto__, "say");

            sinon.spy(a, "hello");

            a.hello();
            a.hello();

            sinon.assert.calledTwice(a.hello);
            sinon.assert.calledOnce(stub);
            sinon.assert.calledTwice(say);
        });
    });
});
```